# How to add one standalone project into another maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, reportng

I have a standalone maven selenium project which is working perfectly fine, now I want my reports to be generated using `ReportNG` and for which I would be doing some customisation to already developed `ReportNG` code.

To customize the `ReportNG` code, I need to download the code and add it to my current maven-selenium project.

Could anybody suggest, how do I add that `ReportNG` code to my maven project and interact with the ReportNG code?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make those projects into two different modules under single project.

Project structure:

```
/test_sample
--/maven-selenium
--/ReportNG
```

Root pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.test.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>test_sample</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>

        <modules>
            <module>maven-selenium</module>
            <module>ReportNG</module>
        </modules>    

    </project>
```

Note: You can also add ReportNG as a dependency to maven-selenium module as per requirement.